# how to split a string based on integers occurrence?

Tags: c#, .net

If a string that contains integers and I want to split it based on integers occurrence. how to do that?

```
string test= "a b cdf 7654321;
```

then I want to store the integer and all words before it, like this

```
string stringBefore="";
// the integer will be last item
string integer="";
```

**Note:**

in my case the integer always will be 7 digits

Comment: What part of the split string do you want to use afterwards? What do possible input strings look like; are there variations in the structure/content of the input string(s)? You might guess it already, i am thinking of substring or regular expressions...

Comment: Is the integer always the last item of the string?

Comment: Is the integer always the last item of the string? yes

Comment: do you want the characters and numbers ? i mean do u want the result to be `abcdf` and `7654321`

Comment: do you want the characters and numbers ? yes I want both

Comment: @shmookh He was asking if you wanted the results without any spaces.

Comment: In your example both `stringBefore` and `integer` are empty strings. I don't think that's what you want..?

Comment: @RufusL I think that was the OP's way of saying I want the result to be two strings.  OP marked me as correct and that was the assumption I made so who knows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Regex.Split` with a capture group to return the delimiter:

```
var ans = Regex.Split(test, @"("\d{7})");
```

If the number is at the end of the string, this will return an extra empty string. If you know it is always at the end of the string, you can split on its occurrence:

```
var ans = Regex.Split(test, @"(?=\d{7})");
```

Answer (score 3):

According to your comments the integer is always 7 digits and it is always the last item of the string.

In that case, just use `Substring()`

```
string test = "a b cdf 7654321";
string stringBefore = test.Substring(0, test.Length - 7); 
string integer = test.Substring(test.Length - 7);
```

Substring just makes a string based on a portion of your original string.

### EDIT

I was a little surprised to find there wasn't a built in way to easily split a string in to two strings based on an index (maybe I missed it).  I came up with a LINQ extension method that achieves what I was trying to do, maybe you will find it useful:

```
public static string[] SplitString(this string input, int index)
{
    if(index < 0 || input.Length < index)
        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
    return new string[] 
    {
        String.Concat(input.Take(input.Length - index)),
        String.Concat(input.Skip(input.Length - index))
    };      
}
```

I think I would rather use a `ValueTuple` if using C# 7, but string array would work too.

Fiddle for everything [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tSdPBa)

Comment: I think a string array is good because it is compatible in return type with the existing `String.Split`

Comment: @NetMage yeah good call, it could be an overload of Split()

Comment: Though I would suggest `Substring` is likely better than `Concat` + `Take`/`Skip` :)